# Can't call a global function

Tags: javascript, apigee

Writing a unit test for Apigee JS policy.

I am trying to call `context.getVariable("env")` from send Msg ()
but `context` is not recognized as a global and hence I cant call`context.getVariable()`.

edit: I cant add `global.context.getVariable("env")` as it is an Object of Apigee's platform

```
    global.context={}
    global.context.getVariable=function(){}

    function logger(){

        function log(msg){

           this.sendMsg(msg)
        }

        var sendMsg = function (){
            context.getVariable("env")
        }

        return {
            log:log,
            sendMsg:sendMsg
        }
    }

    logger().sendMsg()//TypeError: context.getVariable is not a function
```

Why is it happening? and what should I do?

I have tried calling
logger().sendMsg.apply(global) is that ok?

Comment: Why don't you use `global.context` in `sendMsg` ?

Comment: Is `global` actually a reference to the global object? (It is on NodeJS, for instance, and not on browsers; it's not clear to me what environment your code above is meant to be running in.)

Comment: IMO it would be even better to pass the context into logger in the contructor. It never a good idea to tie so closly to global objects

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's an Apigee Edge platform which can parse basic javascript,and has it's own global objects.
DenysSéguret , edited that.
Liam you are totally right, but its not that the case because of the platform